# delete rows app script only working 2nd time through

Tags: google-apps-script

So this app script is for sending emails from the email que sheet and moving them over to the email log sheet.

It appears to be working except that I need to run it twice for it to delete the rows marked "email sent". The first time through, the log says that those rows still say "ready", but then running it again works.

Thanks for your help

```
 function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Email Que");
var rows = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
  var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = rows;   // Number of rows to process
  var now = new Date();

  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Email Log");

  // Fetch the range of cells
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 10, numRows, 9)

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var emailSent = "Email Sent";
  var ready = "Ready";
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var subj = row[0];
    var body = row[1]; 
    var studentEmail = row[4];
    var instEmail = row[5];
    var subEmail = row[6];
    var emailStatus = row[7];
    Logger.log("sending:" + emailStatus);
    if (emailStatus != emailSent && emailStatus == ready) {

      MailApp.sendEmail(studentEmail, subj, body);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 17).setValue(emailSent);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 18).setValue(now);
      var source = sheet.getRange (startRow + i,1,1,21);
      var lastRow = destSheet.getLastRow();
       destSheet.insertRowAfter(lastRow);
      source.copyTo(destSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1,1), {contentsOnly: true});

    };
  };






  for(var i = data.length-1;i>=0;i--){
      var row = data[i];
    var emailStatus = row[7];
Logger.log(emailStatus);
    if(emailStatus == emailSent)
      sheet.deleteRow(i+3);
    //2 header rows
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes an additional execution to delete the rows because you reference the original sheet status in the deletion check -- `data` was read into memory prior to the status being written back.

You can solve this two ways: refresh the `data` variable prior to the deletion loop by re-querying the status of the sheet:

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush() // Ensure pending writes are complete.
data = dataRange.getValues()
```

You could also do this by instead updating the relevant array indexes in `data` while sending emails:

```
data[i][7] = /* the email status */;
data[i][8] = /* the email time */;
```